# How to make setInterval work?

Tags: javascript

So here is my code and I want to add 1 to total every second`

```
var doughnut = 0;
    function myFunction(){

document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = " total: " + setInterval(doughnut +1, 1000) ;


}
```

Can you explain me how setInterval() works and where to put it?

Comment: Why not google *"JavaScript setInterval"*? The first paramater for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is a function to be called for each interval.

Comment: @forrestmid That would do...nothing to update the `total` element.

Comment: I googled it. And I did everythink like I understand it. And that isn't working

Comment: Then -- with respect -- you need to re-read those articles / tutorials. Much more carefully. Programming is an exercise in *details*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does setInterval and setTimeout work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051209/how-does-setinterval-and-settimeout-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setInterval** accepts two arguments:

1. The "**What**": The function to execute
2. The "**When**": interval time in milliseconds to execute that function

Basically each second (1000 ms) the function increments the doughnut value and writes the updated value to the HTML element with id `total`.

Try this:

```
var doughnut = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    doughnut++;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = " total: " + doughnut;
}, 1000);
```