# How to remove a dynamic css after few seconds such that the component is not blocked till that time period

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm from Java background. There we have multithreading to handle these kind of behaviors. I need help with Angular 6. When my component loads. Some simple style is to be applied on that. But after 5 seconds on click of button the style should go away.

**Template:**

```
<div [class.error-warning]="applyStyle">
  <select>
    <option>Apple</option>
    ...
  </select>
</div>

<button (click)="removeStyle()">Remove</button>
```

**Typescript:**

```
applyStyle: boolean=true;

removeStyle() {
  //after 5 seconds
  this.applyStyle=false;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.error-warning {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

I tried `sleep` here but it blocked the entire `dropdown` for 5 seconds. Please help me out. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u5u2zy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for this.

So in your case, your `removeStyle()` method would look like:

```
removeStyle() {
  // after 5 seconds
  setTimeout(() => this.applyStyle = false, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Will it not block the selections for 5 seconds since it is the same thread. I think the entire main flow will wait for 5 secs. Please correct me.

Comment: It will not block your main thread, no. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391634/10657522) a very useful answer to get more information about 'why' it won't block the main thread.