# How to stop a loop with setTimeout() method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a route in my REST API that produces a random food order for the user after they send a request with a bunch of parameters. I have a while loop that loops through potential options and places them into the `randomOrder` array. The loop will run until there are as many items in the random order as `numberOfHeads` specified by the user. The issue is that sometimes it is impossible to create an order that has something for all mouths to feed and as a result, the loop will run forever. As a backstop for this, I would like to add two conditions to the while loop

1. If the amount of items in the random order array matches the `numberOfHeads` specified by the user then the loop can stop.
2. if it tried to do this for a number of seconds but finds itself looping infinitely, I want the loop to stop and simply serve up what it has managed to place in the `randomOrder` array. I have tried to implement this with the `setTimeout()` method but I can't seem to get it to change the `keepCalling` Boolean from `true` to `false` in order to stop the loop. I am also not sure if I can feed two conditions into a while loop where if either condition becomes true the loop stops?

```js
// RANDOM ORDER FILTER/GENERATOR
router.get("/randomorder", async (req, res) => {

    //USERS CHOSEN CATEGORIES SPH & NOP SENT THROUGH THE REQUEST
    const restCats = await req.body.restcategories
    const menueCats = await req.body.menuecats
    var totalSpend = await req.body.totalspend
    const numberOfHeads = await req.body.numberofheads
    const spendPerHead = totalSpend / numberOfHeads

    console.log(spendPerHead)


    let restOptions = await Restaurant.aggregate(
        [{
            $match: {
                categories: {
                    $in: restCats
                }
            }
        }]
    )


    let randomRestOption = restOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * restOptions.length)];
    //RESULT OF ALL MENUE ITEMS MATCHING USER CATEGORIES
    let menueOptions = []

    //FULL RESULT OF BOTH RESTURANTS MATCHING USERS CHOSEN CATEGORIES AND MENUE ITEMS OF THOSE RESTURANTS MATCHING USERS CATEGORIES    


    // LOOPS THROUGH ALL RESTURANT OPTIONS MENUES AND OUTPUTS MENUE ITEMS MATCHING THE USERS CHOSEN CATEGORIES

    randomRestOption.menue.filter(function checkoptions(option) {
        for (let x = 0; x < option.categories.length; x++) {
            // console.log(option)
            if (option.categories[x] === menueCats[0] || option.categories[x] === menueCats[1] || option.categories[x] === menueCats[2] || option.categories[x] === menueCats[3] || option.categories[x] === menueCats[4] || option.categories[x] === menueCats[5] || option.categories[x] === menueCats[6]) {
                // FILTERS RESULTS BASED ON TOTAL SPEND PER HEAD CHOSEN BY USER
                if (option.price <= spendPerHead) {
                    menueOptions.push(option)
                } else if (spendPerHead === undefined) {
                    menueOptions.push(option)

                }


            }
        }

    })

    var keepCalling = true

    const myTimeout = setTimeout(reAssign, 3000)



    function reAssign() {

        keepCalling = false
    }

    myTimeout

    let randomOrder = []

    console.log(keepCalling)

    while (randomOrder.length < numberOfHeads || keepCalling === true) {
        // console.log(keepCalling)
        let randomMenueOption = menueOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * menueOptions.length)];

        // console.log(randomMenueOption)

        function checkDuplicates() {
            let duplicate = ""
            let itemName = randomMenueOption.name
            // console.log(itemName)
            for (let i = 0; i < randomOrder.length; i++) {

                if (itemName === randomOrder[i].name) {
                    duplicate = "duplicate"

                }
                // console.log("loop running")
            }
            // console.log(randomOrder)
            return duplicate
        }

        let checkduplicate = checkDuplicates()


        if (checkduplicate === "duplicate") {
            // console.log("Found Duplicate")

        } else {
            randomOrder.push(randomMenueOption)
        }
        randomOrder.length;
        // console.log(randomMenueOption)
    }


    // console.log(spendPerHead)
    try {
        res.status(201).send({
            randomOrder


        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setTimeout` is an `asynchronous`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051209/how-does-setinterval-and-settimeout-work) that means that it will be executed by the [`event loop` when the `call stack` is empty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

So in your use case it will never will execute because the loop will occupy the `call stack`.

If you want to get the same effect, you can use the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to capture the current time, and in each iteration in the check if it passed the `timeTocancel`.

```
let keepCalling = true;
const startingTime = Date.now();
const timeTocancel = 3000;

while (keepCalling) {
  const currentTime = Date.now();
  if (currentTime - startingTime >= timeTocancel ) break;
  console.log("do things");
}
```